# JDBC dynamic search query

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a **dao layer**

```
  public class UserDao {

    private static String GET_USERS_DOCTORS_FROM_BERLIN = "SELECT * FROM users where occupation = 'doctor' and city = 'berlin'";
    private static String GET_USERS_ENGINEERS_AGE_30 = "SELECT * FROM users where occupation = 'engineer' AND age = 30";

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List getDoctors() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_USERS_DOCTORS_FROM_BERLIN, new RowMapper<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                .....;
            }
        });
    }

    public List getEngineers() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_USERS_ENGINEERS_AGE_30, new RowMapper<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                .....;
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

and a **service layer**

```
 public class UserService {

    public UserDao userDao;

    public List getDoctors() {
        return userDao.getDoctors();
    }

    public List getEngineers() {
        return userDao.getEngineers();
    }

    }
```

What I want is something like this:

```
  public class UserDao {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List getUsers(/* criteria object */Criteria criteria) {
        ....
    }

    }
```

so that I could use it from the service layer. I am looking for best practices on how to implement this.

Comment: Create `MyObjectCriteria` transfer object or use `Map<String, Object>` and construct the query with some tool like QueryDSL (or create your own query builder as its quite simple).

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at QueryDSL

Comment: @PavelHoral Could you please provide an example. I want to go without QueryDSL. I'm not familiar with the pattern and have hard times finding what I need